# Session State Using Client IP

Tags: java, session, ip-address

I am attempting to determine if there is a security flaw using the proposed method of maintaining session state when the client has cookies blocked.

Normally I store a UUID in the clients cookies and auto login if the UUID matches whats stored in the database. However, if the client has cookies blocked, I can't access a UUID on their machine and therefore have to resolve to using their IP address and match against the database that way.

I determine the IP address using:

```
String ip = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if(ip == null) {
    ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

I'm a little green in this area, but I think there might be a security flaw in this approach. For instance, if the user accesses the application on a public wifi network (in a coffee shop, airport, hotel... whatever) it will store the public ip and match their account to that ip. Anyone coming in behind them on that same ip will have complete access to their account unless they specifically remember to log out. How do I prevent this? I'm not totally against using another approach when cookies are blocked besides matching to the ip. I'm just not sure what other approach their might be besides just totally disallowing user logins when cookies are not available. Is this the only truly secure method?

**UPDATE**

Based on T.J. Crowders comment, recent stats show that 2% of users actual have cookies blocked. I chose to rely on cookies for a number of reasons and show a warning when session state cannot be managed due to cookies being blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...but I think there might be a security flaw in this approach. For instance, if the user accesses the application on a public wifi network (in a coffee shop, airport, hotel... whatever)...

Not just that. People who have wireless broadband in their home will all seem to be from the same IP, so if two people who live together both want to use your site simultaneously (maybe one recommended it to the other), they'll conflict.

If you can't use cookies, you could use the old J2EE technique of putting the session ID in every URL. If you're already using J2EE, you can use its built-in support for this ([`HttpServletResponse#encodeURL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) and such), which will use `;jsessionid=token` on the URL. If you aren't, it's simple enough to implement the technique using a query string parameter.

Comment: Does using the querystring method cause problems with bookmarking, emailing urls to friends etc?

Comment: @ryandlf: Yes, it does cause problems. But that's pretty much the only way to track sessions without cookies. Do you really have users blocking cookies? Enough to care about them?

Comment: @ryandlf: Yes, it does, at least in that you end up with people having bookmarks with the session ID in them. You can mitigate that: Make sure that a token for a session that doesn't exist is ignored (handled gracefully). And store the IP of the session in the server-side session state, and then ignore the token if a request comes from a different IP (even if the token is for a valid session), again handling it gracefully.

Comment: Probably not. I may be being a little anal about maintaining session state. Appending to the querystring would probably be a lot more difficult to implement than just blocking logins when cookies are not available.

Comment: @ryandlf: The last I heard, users who block cookies was at about 2%. :-) Now, on the one hand, that's 2% less than you'd have if you supported them. On the other hand...

Comment: It's not really difficult. Just use `<c:url>` (or any other similar tag) in your templates consistently, and make sure encodeRedirectURL is called when redirecting (all MVC frameworks do that for you as well). Not such a big deal.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: It seems that stackoverflow blocks login access without cookies (just tested it out). They seem to be getting by just fine.

Comment: @ryandlf: A **lot** of sites rely on cookies. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: wouldn't all the users lose their session as soon as their IP address changes (DHCP, etc.)?

Comment: @JB Nizet: Problem is i'm using a completely custom templating framework. I agree with you, but in my situation, its a daunting task to rewrite everything to satisfy 2% of possible users.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, they would. Apparent IP addresses change rarely, even on mobile networks. When I say "rarely" I mean in terms of an ongoing, interactive session. (I'm not talking about auto-login stuff that's meant to work "tomorrow".) So you pick your poison: Someone getting access to someone's session easily, or sessions ending periodically when the user's machine's IP changes.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I was aware of that, but I figured if they have to login once in a while because they don't want cookies enabled, so be it. I was mostly just attempting to maintain the session state during the actual browser session. Not when they leave and return at a later date.

Comment: @ryandlf: the question then boils down to an economic question: require the usage of cookies and risk losing some users, or invest some time in encoding URLs. The second solution might end up beneficial, because if there are so many ways to generate URLs in your app, then something must be wrong, and you'd better fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The servlet API allows tracking sessions without cookies, using URL-rewriting (every URL pointing to the app in a given session will contain the session ID). This is automatic if you respect a few rules:

- always use `HttpServletResponse.encodeRedirectURL()` when redirecting
- always use `HttpServletResponse.encodeURL()` when generating a URL (for a link, image or whatever)

Note that the JSTL's `<c:url>` calls `encodeURL()` for you.

Comment: This answer is correct. I chose the other only because in came in first.